# "failed to resume in time" on resumption from background crash

Tags: iphone, ios, multitasking

ok so on going to background I hide everything.   I still get a failed to resume in time error when I switch back.   Why is it crashing in drawRect if everything is hidden?  Any ideas on how to deal with a "Failed to resume" error like this?

```
Incident Identifier: 0E5ADFDF-1EB1-4ECC-9F02-57B37F1BBBA1
CrashReporter Key:   17186e938075dd5907223199eccdc85176f18698
Hardware Model:      iPad1,1
Process:         hexProto [2162]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/31D43A9F-0EF3-4D03-89AC-243B68F75D91/hexProto.app/hexProto
Identifier:      hexProto
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2010-12-10 15:56:11.615 -0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2 (8C134)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
Annexation failed to resume in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 9.880 (user 7.320, system 2.560), 97% CPU
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 7.650, 75% CPU

Thread 0:
0   ImageIO                       0x00009740 ImageIO_ABGR_TO_ARGB_8Bit + 44
1   ImageIO                       0x00006ade ImageProviderCopyImageBlockSetCallback + 210
2   CoreGraphics                  0x00009052 CGImageProviderCopyImageBlockSetWithOptions + 226
3   CoreGraphics                  0x00008f5c CGImageProviderCopyImageBlockSet + 32
4   CoreGraphics                  0x00008c8a img_blocks_create + 182
5   CoreGraphics                  0x00025e1a img_blocks_extent + 42
6   CoreGraphics                  0x00025d06 img_interpolate_extent + 70
7   CoreGraphics                  0x00004e90 img_data_lock + 4376
8   CoreGraphics                  0x00003668 CGSImageDataLock + 104
9   libRIP.A.dylib                0x0000c658 ripc_AcquireImage + 2676
10  libRIP.A.dylib                0x00009c6e ripc_DrawImage + 462
11  CoreGraphics                  0x00003520 CGContextDelegateDrawImage + 44
12  CoreGraphics                  0x000033de CGContextDrawImage + 250
13  UIKit                         0x000148aa -[UIImage drawInRect:blendMode:alpha:] + 1182
14  UIKit                         0x0003affe -[UIImage drawInRect:] + 50
15  hexProto                      0x00047782 -[NormalButton drawRect:] (NormalButton.m:48)
16  UIKit                         0x000132d2 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 258
17  QuartzCore                    0x000152fe -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 86
18  QuartzCore                    0x0001507c backing_callback(CGContext*, void*) + 32
19  QuartzCore                    0x00014af2 CABackingStoreUpdate + 1226
20  QuartzCore                    0x0001435c -[CALayer _display] + 724
21  QuartzCore                    0x0001406a -[CALayer display] + 134
22  QuartzCore                    0x00013fb0 CALayerDisplayIfNeeded + 176
23  QuartzCore                    0x0000956e CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 214
24  QuartzCore                    0x0000937c CA::Transaction::commit() + 184
25  QuartzCore                    0x000092bc CA::Transaction::pop() + 120
26  QuartzCore                    0x0000923a +[CATransaction commit] + 18
```

Comment: Did you implement the applicationWillEnterForeground methods and the like?

Comment: Well, i just leave everything hidden after resigning active .. I never set them back to visible.  Still tries to draw.

Comment: I believe drawRect is sometimes called even if the view is hidden. Any idea what causes it to crash in that method?

Comment: I think it's trying to redraw everything from scratch .. my app is a little complicated so it takes awhile to do that.  Apparently too long for the iPhone os on resumption.

Comment: If that is the case I would recommend trying to override the drawRect method so you can control when it is called.

Comment: I actually just removed it from the superview instead of hiding it.  The crash has gone away.   I then use a performSelectorOnMain thread to re-add back to the superview.   It's a somewhat subtle bug, I had to write a another app to consume memory in order to squeeze this app into this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Instruments (specifically Shark) to find out what is going on.

The reason Springboard is killing your app is because you are coming close to exceeding the allowed 10 seconds (Apple never seems to publish what the exact number is, but general wisdom seems to have it pegged at 10).

```
Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 9.880 (user 7.320, system 2.560), 97% CPU
```

When the program crashes, it may be doing some drawing - how do you know that it's not doing some other task for 8 seconds and then doing drawing for 1.5?  That's where I'd use Shark to find out what's taking the most percentage of CPU time.

Then, analyze that to see what can be done about it.

Comment: Let me know how it goes.  If it doesn't solve your problem, let me know!