# "Failed to resume in time" on a 3.2 iPad?

Tags: ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, crash, timeout

Recently, I upgradie my iPad app's code to support iOS 4.0. I just added the following methods with no actual code in them in my AppDelegate:

- applicationWillEnterForeground:
- applicationDidBecomeActive:
- applicationWillResignActive:
- applicationDidEnterBackground:

I imagined there shouldn't be any change on my 3.2 device, as it shouldn't even be aware of these methods.

However, I received the following "failed to resume in time" time out, on my 3.2 device, which shouldn't do any resuming. This just doesn't make sense to me. Any ideas?

```
Incident Identifier: 5AB41509-89C9-4016-959A-96F466170CED
CrashReporter Key: fedcf4c4ba6f9d644032ce85fe1bc62664631a46
Hardware Model: iPad1,1
Process: News [1530]
Path: /var/mobile/Applications/76A324ED-567E-4253-9A3B-29A61892C5E4/News.app/News
Identifier: News
Version: ??? (???)
Code Type: ARM (Native)
Parent Process: launchd [1]

Date/Time: 2010-11-25 15:49:49.934 +0800
OS Version: iPhone OS 3.2.2 (7B500)
Report Version: 104

Exception Type: 00000020
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
Highlighted Thread: 0

Application Specific Information:
com.NewsPad failed to resume in time
elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 1.580 (user 0.790, system 0.790), 8% CPU
elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.690, 3% CPU

Thread 0:
0 libSystem.B.dylib 0x000016c4 semaphore_wait_signal_trap + 8
1 libSystem.B.dylib 0x0002ecc2 semaphore_wait_signal + 2
2 libSystem.B.dylib 0x000034b4 pthread_mutex_lock + 248
3 CoreGraphics 0x00025064 CGFontCacheLock + 24
4 CoreGraphics 0x00024ffe CGGlyphLockLockGlyphBitmaps + 142
5 libRIP.A.dylib 0x00002720 ripc_RenderGlyphs + 116
6 libRIP.A.dylib 0x0000ab38 ripc_DrawGlyphs + 1004
7 CoreGraphics 0x00024166 CGContextDelegateDrawGlyphs + 26
8 CoreGraphics 0x0002411c draw_glyphs + 720
9 CoreGraphics 0x00023cae CGContextShowGlyphsWithAdvances + 398
10 WebCore 0x00007b0e WebCore::Font::drawGlyphs(WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::SimpleFontData const*, WebCore::GlyphBuffer const&, int, int, WebCore::FloatPoint const&, bool) const + 902
11 WebCore 0x0000775e WebCore::Font::drawGlyphBuffer(WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::GlyphBuffer const&, WebCore::TextRun const&, WebCore::FloatPoint&) const + 154
12 WebCore 0x00007594 WebCore::Font::drawSimpleText(WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::TextRun const&, WebCore::FloatPoint const&, int, int) const + 380
13 WebCore 0x000073f8 WebCore::Font::drawText(WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::TextRun const&, WebCore::FloatPoint const&, int, int) const + 104
14 WebCore 0x00007382 drawAtPoint(unsigned short const*, int, WebCore::FloatPoint const&, WebCore::Font const&, WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::BidiStatus*, int) + 130
15 WebCore 0x00006ea0 -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) _web_drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:ellipsis:letterSpacing:includeEmoji:] + 308
16 UIKit 0x0003c15e -[NSString(UIStringDrawing) drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:lineBreakMode:letterSpacing:includeEmoji:] + 110
17 UIKit 0x0003c0d8 -[NSString(UIStringDrawing) drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:lineBreakMode:] + 44
18 UIKit 0x00047b2c -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] + 1460
19 UIKit 0x00047560 -[UILabel drawTextInRect:] + 44
20 UIKit 0x00047518 -[UILabel drawRect:] + 52
21 UIKit 0x00043f9e -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 246
22 QuartzCore 0x00014ba2 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 86
23 QuartzCore 0x00013b02 -[CALayer _display] + 374
24 QuartzCore 0x0001396e -[CALayer display] + 134
25 QuartzCore 0x000138b6 CALayerDisplayIfNeeded + 178
26 QuartzCore 0x00008b64 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 212
27 QuartzCore 0x00008974 CA::Transaction::commit() + 180
28 QuartzCore 0x0002e15e CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 46
29 CoreFoundation 0x0006f29a __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 406
30 CoreFoundation 0x00022baa CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 1722
31 CoreFoundation 0x000224da CFRunLoopRunInMode + 42
32 GraphicsServices 0x000030d4 GSEventRunModal + 108
33 GraphicsServices 0x00003180 GSEventRun + 56
34 UIKit 0x0000342a -[UIApplication _run] + 374
35 UIKit 0x00001954 UIApplicationMain + 636
36 News 0x00003182 main (main.m:7)
37 News 0x00002e00 start + 32
```

Answer (score 0):

See the similar questions,

["failed to resume in time" on resumption from background crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414467/failed-to-resume-in-time-on-resumption-from-background-crash)

[how to resolve "failed to resume in time" on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782679/how-to-resolve-failed-to-resume-in-time-on-ios)

your problem is because you using some long calculation before the application starts in main thread. Try putting those in thread.

thanks,