# how to resolve "failed to resume in time" on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, crash-dumps

```
Incident Identifier: A664D7F0-B508-4D77-8052-3D15B7612921
CrashReporter Key:   cc6fa311f4d178cd2a1c946ced641fab87e0181d
Hardware Model:      iPhone2,1
Process:         iPORTALs [4155]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/EFCD0F88-675F-47E2-AFA9-9EC4D918881F/iPORTALs.app/iPORTALs
Identifier:      iPORTALs
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-01-24 18:58:22.908 +0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.1 (8B117)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
iPORTALs failed to resume in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 0.730 (user 0.430, system 0.300), 7% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.000, 0% CPU

Thread 0:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00000c98 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00002d64 mach_msg + 44
2   AppSupport                      0x0001009e CPDMMessage + 158
3   AppSupport                      0x0000f3e4 -[CPDistributedMessagingCenter _sendMessage:userInfoData:oolKey:oolData:makeServer:receiveReply:nonBlocking:error:] + 848
4   AppSupport                      0x0000ed76 -[CPDistributedMessagingCenter _sendMessage:userInfo:receiveReply:error:toTarget:selector:context:nonBlocking:] + 618
5   AppSupport                      0x0000deba -[CPDistributedMessagingCenter _sendMessage:userInfo:receiveReply:error:toTarget:selector:context:] + 58
6   AppSupport                      0x0000e08e -[CPDistributedMessagingCenter sendMessageName:userInfo:] + 34
7   iAd                             0x00012bcc -[ADSession sendMessageName:userInfo:] + 100
8   iAd                             0x00013e46 -[ADSession bannerFrameDidChange:orientation:hidden:] + 158
9   iAd                             0x00007aa2 -[ADBannerView _propagateFrame] + 374
10  iAd                             0x000070bc -[ADBannerView sessionDidOpen:withWindowContextId:] + 204
11  iAd                             0x00013114 -[ADSession sessionDidOpenMesssage:userInfo:] + 328
12  CoreFoundation                  0x0004b42c __invoking___ + 60
13  CoreFoundation                  0x0004b2fe -[NSInvocation invoke] + 102
14  iAd                             0x0001849a -[ADMessageProxy forwardInvocation:] + 74
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00049216 ___forwarding___ + 570
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00048f88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 40
17  iAd                             0x00017a92 -[ADDistributedMessagingCenter messagePort:receivedMessage:withData:] + 130
18  iAd                             0x00017f4a ADMessagePortCallBack + 34
19  CoreFoundation                  0x000609ce __CFMessagePortPerform + 242
20  CoreFoundation                  0x00034cdc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
21  CoreFoundation                  0x00034ca0 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
22  CoreFoundation                  0x00027566 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
23  CoreFoundation                  0x00027270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
24  CoreFoundation                  0x00027178 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
25  GraphicsServices                0x000045ec GSEventRunModal + 108
26  GraphicsServices                0x00004698 GSEventRun + 56
27  UIKit                           0x0000411c -[UIApplication _run] + 396
28  UIKit                           0x00002128 UIApplicationMain + 664
29  iPORTALs                        0x000020fa main (main.m:14)
30  iPORTALs                        0x00002070 start + 44

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002d330 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000d6b6c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000d65bc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000d675c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a67a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00073190 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00000c98 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00002d64 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00027c38 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000274c2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00027270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00027178 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x000024e2 RunWebThread(void*) + 362
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00000c98 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00002d64 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00027c38 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000274c2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00027270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00027178 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                      0x0002d686 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                      0x0000b222 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x000042d6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000791d4 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002e1a2 _pthread_cond_wait + 742
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002dd8e pthread_cond_wait + 26
3   CoreMedia                       0x00002334 WaitOnCondition + 4
4   CoreMedia                       0x0000227a FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 66
5   MediaToolbox                    0x00003930 fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 48
6   CoreMedia                       0x0001db6e figThreadMain + 166
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00025060 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0005edfc __CFSocketManager + 540
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x88fff +iPORTALs armv6  <b2d850c13a4042203cb09265c62bc253> /var/mobile/Applications/EFCD0F88-675F-47E2-AFA9-9EC4D918881F/iPORTALs.app/iPORTALs
  0x1f9000 -   0x1fafff  dns.so armv7  <240b8d3f07b4fcb234de598f8e67de1a> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe26fff  dyld armv7  <a11905c8ef7906bf4b8910fc551f9dbb> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30025000 - 0x30055fff  AppSupport armv7  <20908678e860c23207574337097b94f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x30056000 - 0x30063fff  OpenGLES armv7  <6bdd1b930c09cfec7c6c7629551c0cbd> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x3006c000 - 0x3007ffff  libmis.dylib armv7  <e47fe2a55644ffd53fab6547ef59ffab> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x300a2000 - 0x300a4fff  MediaRemote armv7  <68af5b03a2845069af1c63f322b6340d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x300a5000 - 0x301c0fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <6dcc299d5ca75f73afbc98a1b4bd2c7a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x301f5000 - 0x3021efff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <fe6ab911eb680b758f415e20afec8e00> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x30267000 - 0x30273fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <7075593b53fcd90c8d2aa40ba9ff4397> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3028a000 - 0x30323fff  MediaPlayer armv7  <3f29fbbfe5abb8969cda45e0efe42af5> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x30324000 - 0x30379fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <ec6199ca9490baba91f9bc644063bef1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x3037a000 - 0x3043cfff  CFNetwork armv7  <0860d900e5328f349290feaaa3eb6e9a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x3044f000 - 0x3053bfff  MusicLibrary armv7  <6e60d6565924f03d819e330080fc0dfe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x30548000 - 0x30551fff  CoreVideo armv7  <d47b741a05fdbed287a454e834aeede2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x3056c000 - 0x305b7fff  GMM armv7  <140d9a6633393f644c3aa852fe7e7e42> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x305d2000 - 0x305d4fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <ef3a36680985b4db12a778d62f37961f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x3069b000 - 0x30744fff  QuartzCore armv7  <1628da07ea69b89c0b6a5a7d2dc42a24> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x30778000 - 0x3077efff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <e89050debe57ae71a3f0ed2bc9c46145> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x307d9000 - 0x307e0fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0011bd5af0230fcaf63005f7eefa11dd> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x30885000 - 0x309b5fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <9420239a007f28f7aa2163b05053d110> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x309b6000 - 0x309b9fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <0d33b320dcac6cb6a594171f3f8c3b04> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x309ba000 - 0x309c0fff  IAP armv7  <e0bde1a923179f4eaea83b8e8ca602d7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x309ca000 - 0x309e9fff  Bom armv7  <f49558f211241498f37af577051611b3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x309f2000 - 0x309f4fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <8b23f794f02c2f7572a8fe6532630161> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x30bed000 - 0x30c05fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <6d9b86e946a18416f1a50586beabd716> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x30c06000 - 0x30c09fff  CertUI armv7  <4d350d880f67fad89bc143e7159c1ac0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x30c23000 - 0x30cc3fff  Celestial armv7  <aa0773c3d8e022e5a0b307b1db79232a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x30d3b000 - 0x30da9fff  AVFoundation armv7  <05feb4f546c261049ccc8d6a5ccf8790> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x30dfa000 - 0x30e99fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <28583b202a5108a6e93c9990a2f1d576> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x30e9a000 - 0x30ed4fff  IOKit armv7  <6810c1b44dd12227780dc88c76b692e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x30f39000 - 0x30fcafff  AddressBookUI armv7  <99283bc397692fbf3c296b0c1a298aed> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x30fe6000 - 0x30febfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <dabd32c6bac583a6809c2b04c5907acf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x30ffd000 - 0x31030fff  CoreLocation armv7  <e4fb7d0e9675955039ed7a452c3dc935> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x310a7000 - 0x310e9fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <75ae0cfae42b263eb4de427a1b991f9a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x311f8000 - 0x3131efff  MediaToolbox armv7  <ed7b56f98da764e4639611ae6327417b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x31325000 - 0x31563fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <ef4a9b7fdccb3317b5b620ae59a70490> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x31564000 - 0x31565fff  CoreSurface armv7  <586f25579330ac060decd2df4cc05bd8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x31573000 - 0x31573fff  vecLib armv7  <e1d93756e63104d2861a277e8a70df44> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x31574000 - 0x315a4fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <fbd7776498c593443b467d5dc31d2615> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x315b1000 - 0x315fcfff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <9e5eadf1538d47142a4257d2fa5bbdd5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x31600000 - 0x31615fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <1ed920d5a995cd94e71c41631d7c551e> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x31a18000 - 0x31a43fff  DataAccess armv7  <7320fc47e54348166062dcfcc4c17439> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x31a44000 - 0x31a47fff  ArtworkCache armv7  <1f8c5b5641eba117423f385dda0dffa3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
0x31a5d000 - 0x31acbfff  ProofReader armv7  <184b846e1f602485068db7a9c943595f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x31acc000 - 0x32d0cfff  UIKit armv7  <3f1f8f7555dcf93cc4ce2146286bd3f6> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x32da1000 - 0x32da9fff  libkxld.dylib armv7  <e86dd3313cbef5a3a0fb8598f6b0ab18> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x32dc1000 - 0x32dd0fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <17fc35fddaa84a39ca7f260b9f220e4b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x32e3c000 - 0x32e48fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <b715ca60b9e99b3b2b4f8270c478c138> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x32e49000 - 0x32ef2fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <1d74fa3a5cec309857503a51cb2df667> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x32f3a000 - 0x32f90fff  EventKit armv7  <f560f34fe9f784df16c7451a7c3d5a76> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x32fd1000 - 0x330defff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0792bef82e8cde31cb32d06e80262288> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x330df000 - 0x330e7fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <6fb15d72d3ee5444d901dc9ef974a3b3> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x33225000 - 0x33236fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <23a6206a542a6b02dd4c5103af3f9da2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x33237000 - 0x3323afff  ApplePushService armv7  <ee70c20a69f16dd4d43e4489903047bb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x33249000 - 0x33368fff  Foundation armv7  <5cffb5458e87beccdb75770cea676753> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x333be000 - 0x33445fff  Message armv7  <0811df7f3cfa8b9c241cd3bdf06de209> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x337d2000 - 0x337d5fff  IOSurface armv7  <83927fd3641791e5bcdadcca0edd196b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x337d6000 - 0x337f5fff  MobileSync armv7  <3dfdf772f29393bcca4fa113b46cee52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x33821000 - 0x3384afff  ContentIndex armv7  <1b790132dfce754bee3775628f26c8eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x3384b000 - 0x3394ffff  CoreData armv7  <36b5f42fcdceea61bedb2838f8279714> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x3395a000 - 0x33970fff  RawCamera armv7  <bef0590943338e945db7e7cbf274c624> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x33971000 - 0x33a31fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <49029949741e10f21b178b0a4b2df979> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x33a32000 - 0x33a3dfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <19a78978d5908bedc6496470fe542936> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x33a3e000 - 0x33a6dfff  CoreText armv7  <0855144a7f9eeade285f2e7c030f7478> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x33aa2000 - 0x33aabfff  ITSync armv7  <6de2eeb0276458257e6c972f7195a787> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x33c6a000 - 0x33c98fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <41663f59614034ba151e9b4f86e1e141> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x33c99000 - 0x33cd0fff  Security armv7  <4770002d4b443c186dc1e3ddaa1787c8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x33d9e000 - 0x33de8fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <7b2a8cf02f12c636c6db7f5e1906f9f0> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x33de9000 - 0x33e23fff  CoreMedia armv7  <c85a11d97cb8820e325db898b0740f2e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x33f1e000 - 0x33f60fff  MessageUI armv7  <f531fb1f0d3cc0922d643597f5ef23a4> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x33fc0000 - 0x33fc3fff  ActorKit armv7  <bc4365d27ab1fcdf780d64c4d180e417> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x33fc6000 - 0x33fc7fff  DataMigration armv7  <c2889c5e6185ac7ef67fe4147344d410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x3401c000 - 0x34024fff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <a19586adf6b24dabd61f3f56a350a042> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x34099000 - 0x340c8fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <b79a5a4f0506ce17bedeef7799e81687> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x3426c000 - 0x3427afff  Notes armv7  <22108af89c58bf3bf01c7109915dad9c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x3427e000 - 0x34325fff  WebKit armv7  <a8bfa45e5c19efcf95e184e658d61a18> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x34327000 - 0x34330fff  AccountSettings armv7  <aba19b26f9a5e950bd9861c93e265a3a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x34334000 - 0x34337fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <eb847a9560239a5cdd1f19fc6195ecb8> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x3437b000 - 0x3438bfff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <51e935a31a31072ec7a10b7b80adc85e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x3438c000 - 0x343ccfff  CoreAudio armv7  <96e6c0b793449c9e08a507693c956aad> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x3440b000 - 0x344defff  CoreFoundation armv7  <adb562d8b5eaadbb874e255a09d0e04b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x344df000 - 0x34522fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <deafb4c98c723215e43f07c3bf6d77e9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x3452b000 - 0x34538fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <df1574298fea28ad799e1549425b44a4> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x34557000 - 0x3455afff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <6c367af97f27bcdac9362897e0bae546> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x34609000 - 0x3460bfff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <2b26c74e98505a26da656eeb781b16cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x34610000 - 0x34643fff  AddressBook armv7  <59286907142fc76ead3dab9fa3baff5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x346cd000 - 0x346f0fff  iAd armv7  <bb2ef32385f825542b79935a3dc2c98d> /System/Library/Frameworks/iAd.framework/iAd
0x346f1000 - 0x34730fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <f261ea6e5f00e4ba4fda02bb4d7712b4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x34738000 - 0x34738fff  Accelerate armv7  <0601858b149ba0586210ad15b0d41c1e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x34758000 - 0x3475afff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <ee5bb3b14b91bcf192f0d18e9f31c40a> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x3475d000 - 0x349f7fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <795a79616d24a733fae53d9df6c46998> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34aa9000 - 0x34ab0fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <e8c579a3faa687bfb52ba68fbe7b17be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x34ab8000 - 0x34b49fff  ImageIO armv7  <3f421780e67f0219e416287d3e684b54> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x34b4b000 - 0x34b4ffff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <0c10a998f46151b69a9060b5879973cc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x34b50000 - 0x350a2fff  WebCore armv7  <4d60fdc638b6218c26d3c143af5e829c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x350a5000 - 0x350aefff  WebBookmarks armv7  <527d15dc1e27c410c7474f306769a0a3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x350c1000 - 0x35106fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <7de3ef8f02a0af58ef9f58348d5dbc50> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x35143000 - 0x3525cfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <71ef015f1994cf85658df91a50a37815> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x35288000 - 0x352b6fff  MIME armv7  <0cbbaadc15780476e4fcdcdf14bbe4ba> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x353d9000 - 0x3540cfff  iCalendar armv7  <4e036eca5114ea49caf2a80ca52e9d0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x35426000 - 0x35455fff  QuickLook armv7  <0e54a89bb297491e416dbc51a542fdd6> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x35456000 - 0x3546cfff  EAP8021X armv7  <419b97910c4b517f38697a3121775bc7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x3546d000 - 0x35555fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <ef656cb58e56a36789ee17d4d925e9ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
```

Comment: Its not faire to show the app name.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't complete your startup code within approximately 5 seconds, iOS will assume your code has locked up, and will force it to exit.

I guess you may be loading too many resources on startup, or have some bug causing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

Make the large process done while app launch in a thread or timer.